# Attaching metadata to Stripe Payment Link

Tags: metadata, payment

Is it possible to attach metadata to a Stripe Payment link (that directs to Stripe for payment)?

I've set up a basic link to a Stripe payment and have a link to the payment on my site.

What I hope to achieve is to have a rendered mustache template attached to that link some extra parameters/query data, that will act as a metadata set.

ie:
`<a href="www.stripe.com/tk_live_foobarlinktopayment?userid={{user._id}}"> <button>Pay Now</button></a> ...`

I hope to link who's account is making the payment via this metadata.

Comment: Did you managed that?

Comment: Pradeep,  I did manage something in my use-case where I used the Stripe API.
There are 2 replies below that could work, @Ignas reply and mine.
Ignas is more of a command line, curl method.  My method uses node and a checkout session payload needs to be crafted and sent to Stripe API endpoint, to make a "payment attempt" and Stripe will return a redirect link to enter card payments.
See "Creating a Payment Attempt" in Stripe docs.

Answer (score 6):

You can now add some information within the Stripe Payment Link URL directly.

You can set:

- client_reference_id (your reference),
- prefilled_email (prefill the email in the payment link),
- prefilled_promo_code (prefill a promo code).

Documentation: https://stripe.com/docs/payment-links/url-parameters

Comment: I was using `client-reference-id` instead of `client_reference_id` Lol. It was driving me crazy. Thank you, @acoudouy

Comment: Nice! The link is out of date. new link: https://stripe.com/docs/payment-links/url-parameters

Answer (score 5):

The way I've solved this with Payment Links - I generate a unique Payment Link for each purchase and add metadata on Link creation (order_id in my case). This way it gets propagated to webhooks.

Create Payment Link cURL example:

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_links \
  -u sk_test_51INcGzGixr<..> \ 
  -d "line_items[0][price]"=price_1KPia<..> \
  -d "line_items[0][quantity]"=1 \
  -d "metadata[order_id]"=6735
```

This involves a bit more code than you might anticipate with Payment Links, but definitely lighter on implementation side that Checkout.

Also, don't forget to cleanup the Payment Links afterwards:

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_links/plink_1KPoiiGixr8beE1DMeFarexg \
  -u sk_test_51INcGzGixr<..> \
  -d active=false
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to post to the backend endpoint,  using `checkout.sessions.create`.

This creates a payment attempt, where it directs you to a stripe side payment UI.

This payload example is what is passed to the Stripe API,
Though I am using `node-red` and the Stripe payment node, you should be able to do this concept elsewhere.

```
msg.payload = {
    
     payment_intent_data: {    
         metadata : {
            "user_id": msg.user._id,
            "email" : msg.user.user,
         },  
     },
     payment_method_types : ['card'],
     mode: 'payment',
     success_url: 'https://somesite.com/payment_success',
     cancel_url: 'https://somesite.com/payment_cancel',
 
     line_items : [
         {
             quantity : 1,
             price_data : {
                 currency: 'usd',
                 product_data: {
                     name: 'Some Product'
                 },
                 unit_amount: 1200
             }
         }
     ]
}
```